# Get data from error data type

Tags: haskell

If I have an error data type:

```
data Error a = Fail|Ok a
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

if something returns `Error a`, how can I then get that a on its own so I can use it?

Comment: What if it there isn't an `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions). For example:

```
case errorValue of
  Fail -> ... -- Do something if it was a fail
  Ok a -> ... -- Do something involving a if it was OK
```